# Use Request and Response variables in the static web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk, webmethod

Here is my code,

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool FirstAccess()
{
    string app_id = "139295982898884";
    string app_secret = "b5d2a88b56898610d54da2af498e3220";
    //string post_login_url = "http://dev.fitbook.com.asp1-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/v4/FitbookContest.aspx";
    string post_login_url = "http://localhost:4327/FitbookContest.aspx";
    string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

    string code = HttpContext.Current.Request["code"] ?? "";

    try
    {
        if (code == "")
        {
            string dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" + "client_id=" + app_id + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(post_login_url) + "&scope=publish_stream";
            // HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(dialog_url);
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(dialog_url, true);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, HttpContext.Current.Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")), token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }
            access_token = tokens["access_token"];
            TestFB.GetProfilePic(code);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here the lines like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request["code"] ?? "";
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(dialog_url, true);
```

are not working. So is there any alternative solution for it? Is there any way to use it?

Comment: I want to use this method in a jquery ajax post function. So i have to make it as a static and request and response variables are not working means i had written HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(dialog_url, true); but it is not redirecting to this url in this static method!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "is not working"? And suggest you not hide exceptions by catch and return false. At least log `ex.ToString()` so you know what's going on.

Comment: have you tried any other ways to do this? I've also done this in other ways

Comment: @ling.s My whole code is working fine when it is on my server and local but it is not working when i am integrating this page with facebook page tab. When i am opening my page tab app, it is not opening a pop up to allow for an app. So can you tell me the proper steps integration of facebook page tab app using c#.net. you can refer this link to come to know my actual problem in detailed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827155/how-to-open-go-to-app-pop-up-on-facebook-page-tabs-checkbox-click. May you tell me some other ways?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this,

```
string dialog_url = "~http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" + "client_id=" + app_id + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(post_login_url) + "&scope=publish_stream";
```

and, redirect as false indicate Whether execution of current page should terminate

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(dialog_url,false);
```

Simply try this:

```
string code = HttpContext.Current.Request["code"];

if (code==null)
{
  // code
}
```

and I think the problem is in the line. You didn't specify accesstoken

```
string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, HttpContext.Current.Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);
```

Comment: So `Redirect("dialog_url",true)` or `Redirect(dialog_url,true)`?

Comment: It is still not redirecting.I have tried above both options.I am not getting any error.

Comment: what you are doing with this? I'll tell some other ways

Comment: My whole code is working fine when it is on my server and local but it is not working when i am integrating this page with facebook page tab. When i am opening my page tab app, it is not opening a pop up to allow for an app. So can you tell me the proper steps integration of facebook page tab app using c#.net. you can refer this link to come to know my actual problem  in detailed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827155/how-to-open-go-to-app-pop-up-on-facebook-page-tabs-checkbox-click